# same pubspec.yaml - build for both ddc and dart2js with debug

Tags: build, dart, dart-dev-compiler

In current state of project I want to build both for ddc and dart2js with debug  info. Is this possible with same `pubspec.yaml`?

Using the recommended setting for ddc, the debug mode is associated with ddc.

```
web:
  compiler:
    debug: dartdevc
```

While the `dart2js`build is obtained with `--mode=release` in commandline.

Only way I find now is by un/comment out the `ddc`section from the `pubspec.yaml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the command line flag instead of the `pubspec.yaml` setting

```
pub build --web-compiler=dartdevc
```

See also https://webdev.dartlang.org/tools/dartdevc

The disadvantage is, that IntelliJ currently doesn't allow to specify parameters to `pub serve` AFAIK.